# SQL Date option

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a little doubt, I want to create a table that had a date that can't be bigger the 2012/12/31, i searched on google but only had exemples on SELECT. I'm gonna put an example:

```
 CREATE TABLE example(
 IDExample number (8) primary key,
 DateExample date // Here i want to put that condition, is it possible?
 );
```

Comment: This could be either a yes or no depending on your DBMS so, what's your DBMS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server you can add check contraint on the column in the following way.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.example ADD CONSTRAINT CK_DateExample
    CHECK (DateExample < '20130101')
```

If you're using Oracle, the syntax is very similar:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.example ADD CONSTRAINT CK_DateExample
    CHECK (DateExample < DATE '2013-01-01')
```

Comment: +1 Apparantly, this also works for [Oracle](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/check.php).

Comment: @Lieven Thanks for the link. I hope Oracle engine will understand the date format too.

Comment: @P3druh77 Does a syntax problem occur?

Comment: @P3druh77 - *Not working* isn't helping anybody. What is not working? Syntax error? Wrong date format? What is the error message if any?

Comment: literal does not match format string. The suggestio is correct the format string...

Comment: @P3druh77 - that should be pretty self explanatory?! You should change `'20130101'` with something your server can handle. What that is depends on you configuration of Oracle but I would try `'2013\01\01'` for starters.

Comment: Found it, thanks!!

    DateExample date check (DateExample >= to_date('2013.01.01', 'YYYY.MM.DD'),